# How to change the Maximum Number of Customer Login Attempts?

Tags: magento2, customer, login, customer-account, security

I want to know how to change the customer's maximum login attempts in Magento 2. I know how to do it for the admin but can't figure it out for customers.

Comment: Refer http://www.emagentosupport.com/2018/12/magento-2-admin-login-into-same-account.html

Answer (score 4):

Check In your store configuration

```
Store > Configuration > Customer > Customer Configuration > Maximum Login Failures to Lockout Account
```

By default the value is 10 you can change it to 0 to disable the setting.

Answer (score 2):

You can change customer maximum attempts from `

> Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customers Configuration ->
>   Password Option

**Now set 0 for unlimited time from Maximum Login Failures to Lockout Account**

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the help!

Comment: its now working for api. any suggestion? Post:http://magento.lan/rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token?username=user@gmail.com&password=xyz123&websiteId=0